# With javascript, remove all but last object based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object.

```
[
    {
        "name":"keith",
        "skill":"kool",
        "job" :"rapper"
    },{
        "name":"mike",
        "skill":"killer",
        "job" :"rapper"
    },{
        "name":"Alan",
        "skill":"js",
        "job" :"slacker"
    },{
        "name":"Dre",
        "skill":"Dr",
        "job" :"rapper"
    },{
       "name":"Garth",
       "skill":"Guitar",
       "job":"singer"
    }

]
```

I only need the last object of each job. All other jobs can be deleted. I need to keep the order as well, so the expected object will look like this:

```
[{
        "name":"Alan",
        "skill":"js",
        "job" :"slacker"
    },{
        "name":"Dre",
        "skill":"Dr",
        "job" :"rapper"
    },{
       "name":"Garth",
       "skill":"Guitar",
       "job":"singer"
    }
]
```

The "job" value may be any string, it's unknown.

How do I delete all but the last duplicate objects based only on a certain field?

Comment: you don't have an object but an array of objects.

Comment: What have you tried? [There are enough posts on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+duplicates+array)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is called `people`;

```
var filteredPeople = [], foundJobs = [];
for (var i = people.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (foundJobs.indexOf(people[i].job) < 0) {
        foundJobs.push(people[i].job);
        filteredPeople.unshift(people[i]);
    }
}
```

should do it.

Comment: Why not simply iterate backwards?

Comment: Of course you'd likely use `.unshift()` instead of `.push()`, if you care about the order of the results

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your array (I named it jobs, see demo) and push the objects with a unique job in an other array. I created a helper function to check if there is an object with a certain job already in the new array.

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/789nrcg0/1/)

```
var newarray=[]; //array to store objects with unique job property

//loop through the jobs array
for(var i=0;i<jobs.length;i++){

    if(!checkProp(jobs[i].job, newarray)){
        newarray.push(jobs[i]);
    }
}

console.log(newarray); //display output in console

//helper function to check if there is an object in the array with a  
//certain value for the job property
function checkProp( prop, arr ) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if( arr[i].job === prop )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over all entries if the job has been seen before, then filter out nulls from the array:

```
seen = {};
result = [];
for (int i=list.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    var key = "!"+list[i].job; // avoid "constructor" problem
    if (!seen[key]) {
        seen[key] = 1;
        result.push(list[i]);
    }
});
result.reverse();
```

I am adding `!` in front of the job before using it as a key into `seen` because the name `constructor` is always present in objects (and, incidentally, "constructor" doesn't sound so weird as a job name).